# How can I save a blob as a video using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, video, blob

I am trying to download some Facebook videos using JavaScript. However, when I go to the `src` tag of the video, all I see is a blob. Is there a way to convert that blob to a video file? Here is an example blob URL: https://www.facebook.com/26dbb6da-4503-434a-a4a7-aabca49a3d46

Do I need anything else beside the blob URL to download that video?

Thanks.